# PHP - else argument for array not working

Tags: php, mysql

Currently have a list of Dates from Date1 to Date2 in an array, I'm then trying to bring dates from a mysql database into an array. From there the dates which are in the database and present between date1 and date2 should say Taken as those dates which aren't in the database are not taken. The code so far is:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "apple", "Orange1", "cal");
$date1 = new DateTime('2014-06-10'); // From date: 10/06/2014
$date2 = new DateTime('2014-06-30'); // To date: 30/06/2014
$datesTaken = array();
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `events` FROM `events`"); //get dates from events table

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { //iterate over each row in SQL
    $datesTaken[] = new DateTime($row['date1']); //add taken dates into array  //add dates to the $datesTaken array.
}

while ($date1 <= $date2) { //loop until dates are equal
    if (in_array($date1, $datesTaken)) { //if the date is in the datesTaken array it is taken
        echo $date1->format("Y-m-d") . " taken. <br />"; //Dates which are taken
    }
    else {
        echo $date1->format("Y-m-d") . " not taken. <br />"; //Dates which aren't taken
    }

    date_add($date1, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 day')); //adding a day to $day1 then looping through again unless $date1 is greater
}

?>
```

At the moment the outcome from the code is:

> 2014-06-10 not taken.
>   2014-06-11 not taken.
>   2014-06-12 not taken.
>   2014-06-13 not taken.
>   2014-06-14 not taken.
>   2014-06-15 not taken.
>   2014-06-16 not taken.
>   2014-06-17 not taken.
>   2014-06-18 not taken.
>   2014-06-19 not taken.
>   2014-06-20 not taken.
>   2014-06-21 not taken.
>   2014-06-22 not taken.
>   2014-06-23 not taken.
>   2014-06-24 not taken.
>   2014-06-25 not taken.
>   2014-06-26 not taken.
>   2014-06-27 not taken.
>   2014-06-28 not taken.
>   2014-06-29 not taken.
>   2014-06-30 not taken.

The two dates currently in the database with the same format are: "2014-06-14" and "2014-06-15" I've tried completely removing the mysqli query and just simply having

```
$datesTaken = array("2014-06-14","2014-06-15");
```

Still the outcome is the same. Very new to programming, Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your SQL doesn't return a column called date1, but you do work on a column with that name here: $datesTaken[] = new DateTime($row['date1']);.  That could be a problem

Comment: You are querying for a column called `events` from the `events` table then in your loop you are referencing a column named `date1`.

Comment: Since he's using `mysqli_fetch_array`, that should be `$row[0]`.

Comment: Also, the formula for finding overlaps is `if(dateStart < eventEnd && dateEnd > eventStart)`. This will find any overlap and you could very easily just add this to your query to find any events that overlap `dateStart` and `dateEnd`. Including events that are on the edge or completely encompass the entire search timeframe. As it is, you are querying for EVERY event and looping over them. 5 years from now you would probably be looping over a lot of unnecessary events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong, as I am not sure the column name, could be either of the following possibilities.

```
SELECT `events` as date1 FROM `events`
```

or

```
SELECT `date1` FROM `events`
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$row` array doesn't contain the key "date1".  Since you're using `mysqli_fetch_array`, the `$row` array will contain the key "0" and a key that matches your column name, which is "events" (both with the same value).

To help with finding this sort of problem in the future, I suggest turning on strict errors in your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

(Depending on your PHP version, the `| E_STRICT` may not be necessary.)

This will cause various programming mistakes, such as trying to access an array element that doesn't exist, to show an error message rather than quietly doing the wrong thing.